# laravel route and parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do a search by id.

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('PLAYERController@edit')}}">
<input type="text" name="id">
```

controller

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        $id=$request->id;
        $ply = Player::find($id);
        return view::make('player.edit')->with(compact('ply'));
    }
```

route

```
Route::get('/player/edit/{id}', 'PLAYERController@edit');
```

edit.blade.php

```
<td>{{$ply[first_name]}}</td>
```

I am getting undefined variable first_name error.

Answer (score 0):

your Route must be as below since its post reuqest

```
Route::post('/player/edit', 'PLAYERController@edit');
```

also you can do action in form as below

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('/player/edit')}}">
<input type="text" name="id">
```

if you are trying make get request then you have to change controller to

```
    public function edit($id)
        {

            $ply = Player::find($id);
if($ply){
            return view::make('player.edit')->with(compact('ply'));
}
        }
```

Comment: @KenGraham.glade to here its helped you

Answer (score 0):

`$ply` is an Object. Try this

```
<td>{{ $ply->first_name }}</td>
```

This won't raise any errors if `$ply` object being `null`

And, you don't need that `{id}` parameter in your route. Because you get the id through the post request.

```
Route::get('/player/edit', 'PLAYERController@edit');
```